# How do I vs2019 for C++ from command line with a specified config file?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm aware that I can install vs2019 by checking the option in GUI interaction. Actually, I've setup a box this way. I'm trying another way.

[image]

Per [ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/command-line-parameter-examples?view=vs-2019) I can do the job from command line.

```
vs_enterprise.exe --installPath C:\minVS ^
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor ^
--passive --norestart
```

The command above would install a minimal instance of Visual Studio, with no interactive prompts but progress displayed.

How do I use this approach to install vs2019 for C++ from command line with a specified config file?

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "components": [
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler",
    "Microsoft.Component.MSBuild",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IntelliCode",
    "Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreIde",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.14.Latest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions.CMake",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForBoostTest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForGoogleTest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ASAN",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop"
  ]
}
```

This configuration file is exported from vs2019 bootstrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously saved `.vsconfig` [installation configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/import-export-installation-configurations?view=vs-2019) can be installed or added with the `--config` command line option. From the [Using --config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/command-line-parameter-examples?view=vs-2019#using---config) examples:

> - Using `--config` to install the workloads and components from a previously saved installation configuration file:
>
>   ```
>   vs_enterprise.exe --config "C:\.vsconfig" --installPath "C:\VS"
>   ```
> - Using `--config` to add workloads and components to an existing installation:
>
>   ```
>   vs_enterprise.exe modify --installPath "C:\VS" --config "C:\.vsconfig"
>   ```

The blog post [Configure Visual Studio across your organization with .vsconfig](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/configure-visual-studio-across-your-organization-with-vsconfig/) has more about `.vsconfig` files, including how to associate one with an individual solution.